# Odoo 13 - Add second sum_field to Kanban Column ProgressBar

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, odoo-13

I'd like to know if there is a way to modify the Kanban Column ProgressBar in order to allow a second sum_field, to show it beside the existing sum_field.

I found out the progressbar js code seems to be in **addons/web/static/src/js/views/kanban/kanban_column_progressbar.js**, but I don't know how or what to do to add that second sum_field.

Should I inherit the js file in some way? If so, how can I do that?

This is the progressbar I'm talking about:

[Odoo CRM Kanban ProgressBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEz7v.png)

This is the idea I have in mind:

[Same ProgressBar, but with a second computed field besides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2z19.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter the [KanbanView.ColumnProgressBar](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/web/static/src/xml/kanban.xml#L108) template, compute and add the total before the last div.

The following example compute the total of `planned_revenue` in each column:

```
<t t-inherit="web.KanbanView.ColumnProgressBar" t-inherit-mode="extension">
    <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_kanban_counter_side')]" position="before">
        <t t-set="total" t-value="0"/>
            <t t-foreach="widget.columnState.data" t-as="data_record">
                <t t-set="total" t-value="total + data_record.data.planned_revenue"/>
            </t>
        <b class="ml-2"><t t-esc="total"/></b>
    </xpath>
</t>
```

Comment: Yep, makes sense. This seems a lot more practical than what I just did-- Inherited the ProgressBar js code and adapted it for that extra field.